# Generate Zip File - download PDF from Url and Generate Zip to Download in Browser - Broken PDF

Tags: java, rest, pdf, fileoutputstream, zipoutputstream

I have create Rest Service and I am trying to Generate Zip file. This Zip file created from muliple PDF files which are downloaded using method `InputStream inpuStream =  new URL(url).openStream()` . I am able to Generate Zip file Which included PDF files but PDF files are broken.
Even If i try to Generate it from String its coming as broken PDF and i am getting Error message "Not a supported File Type or file is broken or damaged". Its simple code but seems like i am unable to track the mistake.
I have provided my controller , service method for your reference.
1)Controller:

```
 @GetMapping("/getZipFile")
public void getZipFile(HttpServletResponse response) throws RestException {
    try {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = generateZipService.getZipFile();
        ServletOutputStream responseOutPutStream = response.getOutputStream();
        response.setContentType("APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM");
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        response.addHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"GeneratedZipFile.zip\"");
        responseOutPutStream.write(baos.toByteArray());
        responseOutPutStream.flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RestException("Error In downloading Zip File");
    }

}
```

2)Service Method

````
  public ByteArrayOutputStream getZipFile() throws Exception{
     List<ZipFileName> zipFileNames=     zipFileNameDao.getZipFileName();
       ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
       ZipOutputStream zipOut= new ZipOutputStream(baos);
       for (String fileName : zipFileNames) {
             InputStream inpuStream = new ByteArrayInputStream( "this is test to generarte pdf test file this is test tdfsfs this is test to generarte pdf test file this is test tdfsfs".getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8) );
             createZipFile(inpuStream,zipOut,fileName);
             inpuStream.close();
         }
        zipOut.flush();
        baos.flush();
     
        zipOut.close();
        baos.close();
        return baos;
 }

3)createzipfile from service method :

```private void createZipFile(InputStream inputStream, ZipOutputStream zipOut,String fileName) throws IOException {
     
     ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(fileName+".pdf");
     BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
     
     zipOut.putNextEntry(zipEntry);
     zipOut.write(IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream));
    
     zipOut.closeEntry();
     bis.close();
     inputStream.close();
 }
````

Also ,  Another question is about using channels. I read channels are better when you have large files to downlaod from server . I have less then 20 kb of file so should I use Java.nio or just Zipoutputstream is fine.

I try with "response.setContentType("APPLICATION/ZIP")" but it didnt change the outcome of the project.
Thank you for your help..

Comment: Where do you generate pdfs? I only see you creating a text putting it into a zip using a pdf file name. But merely storing something using a pdf file name does not make it a pdf file.

Comment: thank you for your comment. the issue was with the authentication . I have to provided authentication while i try to openstream which is why i was getting broken pdf. I would like to close this post.. I am good.

Comment: Well, you could create an answer and (after awaiting period) mark it as accepted. Your solution might be the solution for other people's problems, too. Or you can delete it.

Answer (score 0):

The code worked fine only thing missing was to pass authentication with the openStream() method because of which I was getting the broken PDF. I opened the pdf with notepad++ and found the error ..
I resolved it.
Thank you